# htaccess triggered internal server error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I made a simple rule to redirect users to the virtual directory **login/** when they go to **login.php** and redirect the users to virtual directory **register/** when they go to **register.php**.
But after putting the **.htaccess** file in the directory, it threw this error :-

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

Here's **.htaccess**

```
#ErrorDocument 404 /

RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80


RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php
RewriteRule ^register/?$ register.php
```

What possibly wrong I'm doing here ?
I'm running a WAMP server.

Apache error log

```
[Sat Nov 16 02:56:29.603789 2013] [core:alert] [pid 5972:tid 1592] [client ::1:55562] C:/wamp/www/m/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Check the apache error log. You will see any misconfiguration errors there.

Comment: @Ankur; Did you enable mod_rewrite?

Comment: @Ankur That error means you don't have mod_rewrite enabled.

Comment: Enabling mod_rewrite seems to have fixed the problem..thanks @anubhava

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you.